# prevent session initialization in incomplete php object

Tags: php, oop, session

i'm using MVC pattren and start the sessions in the construct of the Controller class .
my class (expect core's one) are loaded by spl_autoload_register().
i create an AJAX class that's a subclass of the Controller in order to prevent user from executing multiple ajax request in a short interval of time i use the following code

```
class ajax extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(false);
        if ($this->checkAttempts())
            exit();   
    }

    public function checkAttempts()
    {
        $counter = 0;
        $attempts = Session::get(AJAX);
        $attempts = ($attempts === false) ? [] : $attempts;
        if ($attempts === false)
            Session::set(AJAX, []);
        else
            $this->setAttempt();
        foreach ($attempts as $key => $attempt)
        {
            if (time() - intval($attempt) <= 10)
                $counter++;
            else
                Session::destroyArray(AJAX, $key);
        }
        return $counter >= 5;
    }

    public function setAttempt()
    {
        return Session::setArray(AJAX, time());
   }

   //ajax methods ...
 }
```

the problem is when i open another Controller such as home (haven't a construct)

```
class home extends Controller {
    public function index(){...}
}
```

the script initialize the sessions in the checkAttepmt method of the ajax class it mean the method checkAttepmt it called and only the session are set for eg when i echo something nothing appear !

when i print the session variable in Home controller i found the session set in the ajax controller exists ( i clear them in each test ) .

i used debug_backtrace() like this to figure out the problem

```
class ajax extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(false);
        $_SESSION['trace'] = debug_backtrace();
    }
}
```

the result is

```
[trace] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\__path__\application\core\application.php
                    [line] => 24
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => ajax
                    [object] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
                        (
                            [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => ajax
                        )

                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => D:\__path__\public\index.php
                    [line] => 15
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => Application
                    [object] => Application Object
                        (
                            [controller:protected] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
                                (
                                    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => ajax
                                )

                            [method:protected] => getConfirmMsg
                            [params:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )
```

what's the relation between the __PHP_Incomplete_Class and this problem and how to slove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the problem ! there's some jQuery ajax requersts fired before the click event happen i fix it now .